# The length of array changes after passing it a function

Tags: c, arrays

I use the following code to pass an array to a function and print its size before and after calling the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int passing_array(int array[]) {
    int size = sizeof(array);
    printf("The size after passing: %d\n", size);
}

int main () {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3};

    int size = sizeof(a);
    printf("The size before passing: %d\n", size);

    passing_array(a);

    return 0;
}
```

After running the code, I got a strange result:

> The size before passing: 12
>
> The size after passing: 8

My question is: why does the size of the array change from 12 to 8?

Comment: Because the array name decays to a pointer when passing as function argument.

Comment: There are so many duplicates of this question on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int passing_array(int array[]) {
    int size = sizeof(array);
    printf("The size after passing: %d\n", size);
}
```

is the same as

```
int passing_array(int* array) {
    int size = sizeof(array);
    printf("The size after passing: %d\n", size);
}
```

Hence, `size` is the size of a pointer.

Comment: Just to complement, the first call returns 12 because the size of int in that machine is 4 bytes so and array of 3 elements occupy 12 bytes.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question.

Comment: @YuanTian, you are welcome. Happy programming.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass an array to a function, it decays to a pointer to the first element of the array.  So `int array[]` in your parameter list is really `int *array`, and `sizeof` is returning the size of the pointer.

Comment: Thank you very much, too. But I can only accept one answer, sorry.